# Json file not displaying data in html table

Tags: angular

In my application data comes from webapi. following is the code

```
---
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        string dte = "2021-01-01";
         string  uname = "baiju";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=LAPTOP-30BV9E85\\SQLSERVER;Database=Lekshmi;    user id=sa;password=baiju");


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_Bookstatus3", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dte", dte);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname);
        //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from busmaster", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return new JsonResult(ds.Tables[0]);

    }
---
got following output after breakpoint in code
```

### [image]
in browser following output

[{"ID":100,"01":null,"02":null,"03":null,"04":null,"05":null,"06":null,"07":null,"08":null,"09":null,"10":null,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null,"18":null,"19":null,"20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"23":null,"24":null,"25":null,"26":null,"27":null,"28":null,"29":null,"30":null,"31":null},{"ID":101,"01":null,"02":null,"03":null,"04":null,"05":null,"06":null,"07":null,"08":null,"09":null,"10":null,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null,"18":null,"19":null,"20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"23":null,"24":null,"25":null,"26":null,"27":null,"28":null,"29":null,"30":null,"31":null}]

---

it is a table format like

ID  01 02 03.......................................................31

100 null null.......................................................null

101 null null.......................................................null

My requirement is to display this in angular page

code in angular

appcomponent.ts

```html
 import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {SharedService} from 'src/app/shared.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',enter code here
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: SharedService){}

  DepList: any=[];
  ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getList().subscribe(data=>{
   this.DepList=data;
   this._object = Object;
   
   console.log(this.DepList);
   });
```

appcomponent.html

```html
<table id="tbl2" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of _object.keys(DepList[0]); let i = index">{{header}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of DepList; let i = index">
        <td *ngFor="let objKey of _object.keys(row); let j = index">{{ row[objKey] }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

but iam getting the out put as
[image]

my requirement is it shouldbe in order like
start with Id 01 02 ....30
and next line with  100
next with 101

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [];
  headers: string[];

  constructor(private service: SharedService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = data;
      this.headers = Object.keys(this.data[0]).sort()
      this.headers.splice(0, 0, this.headers.pop());
    });
  }
}
```

in component.html file

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let header of headers">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let key of headers">{{row[key]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this code is not working iam using angular 11

Comment: This is not problem of angular.Its only displaying table issue in bootstrap

Comment: if it is 10 columns like ID 01....09 then it display fine.if its more than 10 .column no 10 will be the first column onwards

Comment: it is not a problem with the angular version. I used hard-coded data to test.
can you hard-code that data instead of calling the service and try it?.
its work for me

Comment: check this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aakgnd

Comment: error in this line .this.headers.splice(0, 0, this.headers.pop());

Comment: stackblitz example work fine. is an error in your code?. what is the error?

Comment: following is  error////(property) AppComponent.headers: string[]
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
View Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available

Comment: error is redline under this.headers.pop()

Comment: it is working fine in stackblitz and my pc, which means the data get from your service may be different from my hard-coded data.
try to hard code that data instead of calling the service. if it is working you may find the issue. also, you can use  headers: any; instead of   headers: string[];

Comment: Finally I corrected it//headers: any[] = [];
  data: any = [];
  
  constructor(private service: SharedService){
   
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = data;
      this.headers = Object.keys(this.data[0]).sort()
      this.headers.splice(0, 0, this.headers.pop());
    });

  }